# Apply wheres programmaticaly to the result of a store procedure in Linq to SQL

Tags: linq, stored-procedures, optimization, linq-to-sql

Given a store procedure, say 'mySP', with takes one argument and returns a set of results, I would like to filter that resultset programmatically using a list of conditions.

**Step1:** the store procedure is added to the *dbml* file.

**Step2:** the code:

```
Dim resultIQueryableSet As IQueryable(Of mySPAutoGeneratedType) = datacontext.mySP(myParam).AsQueryable()
Dim querySet As IQueryable(Of mySPAutoGeneratedType) = (From x In resultIQueryableSet Select x)
For each condition in listOfCondition
 querySet = querySet.where(Function(el As mySPAutoGeneratedType) el.condition = condition)
Next
' finally, prepare the result
Dim resultSet As List(Of mySPAutoGeneratedType) = querySet.ToList()
```

**Step3:** the resultSet becomes the datasource of a gridview

I'm wondering whether this is the best approach. My concern is about optimization. When running this code, is the set of where clauses applied only once (at the end, when the .ToList() is called) or is there a better way to handling this.

If it is of any help, I'm using vbnet, .net 4 and sql server 2008r2.

Comment: This will get all the data from the database and filter it in code. Could you not rewrite the stored procedure as a Linq query?

Comment: I know that, but since the data will not be so much and it easier to perform that set of where looping on a set of conditions, I'd prefer to go with this approach.. unless it is VERY bad..

Comment: Well it's not "bad" per se, it's just very inefficient. You are bringing all that data back from the database and potent discarding most/all of all.

Comment: Actually the store procedure is in charge of the biggest part of the filter (the real sp takes 8 parameters to filter). The where in the code is performed on 100 rows (more or less). My biggest concern is about the Stored procedure -> AsQueryable -> .Where -> ToList()